# Android Missed Call Notification Sound/Chime

Tags: missed-calls

Consider this scenario. I am listening to music on my android phone and I have DND mode on and set to *priority only*. A spam call comes in and my phone dutifully blocks the call right away **but** the android missed call notification sound/chime plays. I think it is similar to the sound the phone plays when you hang up at the end of a normal phone call.

I would very much like to silence this sound so that it *never* plays when a call is missed and sent straight to voice mail.

Is it possible to do this with an app or in the android settings?